# AutoRest from Swagger Documentation - IEnumerable<long> generated as IEnumerable<long?>

Tags: c#, asp.net, swagger, swashbuckle, autorest

I have a project which is using ASP.NET MVC 5, Swashbuckle, and AutoRest. When I generate a client for my API using Autorest, my parameter is being converted from an `IEnumerable<long>` to `IEnumerable<long?>`

### Controller Method

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Foo([FromBody] IEnumerable<long> ids)
{
    // do work
}
```

### Resulting AutoRest Signature

```
Task<HttpOperationResponse<IList<ResponseModel>> FoWithMessageAsync(IList<long?> ids, ...)
```

### What I've tried

- Using a Get Method. Results in a "multi" type, which is a known bug in Autorest [known bug in AutoRest](https://github.com/Azure/autorest/issues/717).
- Eliminating [FromBody] Attribute
- Wrapping the IEnumerable in a custom model

It's kind of an odd error, but I've worked with Swagger and Autorest for a while, so I can only assume its either an obscure bug/configuration (possible) or I missed something dumb (likely). Thanks in advance for any help.

### Update

This is the Swagger Spec that Swashbuckle has generated

```
{
    "swagger": "2.0",
    "info": {
        "version": "v1",
        "title": "FooBar",
    },
    "host": "localhost:5000",
    "schemes": [
        "http"
    ],
    "paths": {
        "/api/v1/Foo": {
            "post": {
                "operationId": "foo",
                "consumes": [
                    "application/json",
                    "text/json"
                ],
                "produces": [
                    "application/json",
                    "text/json"
                ],
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "name": "ids",
                        "in": "body",
                        "description": "",
                        "required": true,
                        "schema": {
                            "type": "array",
                            "items": {
                                "format": "int64",
                                "type": "integer"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "OK",
                        "schema": {
                            "type": "array",
                            "items": {
                                "$ref": "#/definitions/Foo"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "404": {
                        "description": "NotFound"
                    },
                    "500": {
                        "description": "InternalServerError"
                    }
                },
                "deprecated": false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you can paste the relevant part of the api specification through which you are generating this, it would help in getting an answer.

Comment: @SumitMaingi, I've added the swagger spec that Swashbuckle has generated.

Comment: sorry kevin, tried for 15 minutes (which is my limit), couldn't get it to work

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you how to solve your problem in the *Swagger* file and using the **latest** version of AutoRest (https://github.com/Azure/autorest), but I have no clue of Swashbuckle, i.e. whether it can generate the following:

```
"200": {
    "description": "OK",
    "schema": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
          "x-nullable": false,
          "type": "integer",
          "format": "int64"
        }
    }
},
```

Note that I have spelled out an inline schema instead of referencing `"$ref": "#/definitions/Foo"` to keep it simple.
The important thing is to set `"x-nullable": false`, which overrides the default behavior of going nullable (expecting the worst from server responses).
In your case, the attribute has to be added to the referenced schema `.../Foo`.

This feature is only days old, so make sure to pull the latest AutoRest.

Comment: Sadly, Autorest is generating my client as part of a Continuous Integration step. The question is more concerning how to get Autorest to generate the swagger than the swagger itself.

Comment: you mean how Swashbuckle generates the swagger? AutoRest just adheres to the Swagger spec (or at least tries to). As mentioned I never used Swashbuckle but there might be a way to convince it to generate `x-nullable: false`, at least I found some mentions in their repo (https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/blob/e0053e1864defa3c4f73ca2a960eb876e257cc9e/Swashbuckle.Dummy.Core/SwaggerExtensions/ApplySchemaVendorExtensions.cs)

Comment: Yes, the issue boils down to the differences between languages that either have a concept of or assumption of nullable primative types. Swashbuckle gets around this with the primitive type by marking a property with the [Required] Attribute. An IEnumerable of primitives is throwing AutoRest through the loop though. It's just an issue somewhere between AutoRest and Swashbuckle, but it somewhere in C# land, before the Swagger is ever generated.

Comment: Yes the `Container<SomeType>` is a real problem, unfortunately one cannot mark the *inner* thingy as required (only the container itself, but who cares), which is one of the reasons `x-nullable` was added :/ hopefully there will be Swashbuckle support for that soon